# calling angular Controller/Function from Javascript

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am really new to Angular.  I am trying to execute my code defined in a controller in my app.js file.  I need to do that by a javascript.
How to do that?

app.js file

```js
app.controller('MyLocCtrl',function($firebaseObject){
  myfunction = function () {
const rootRef =  firebase.database().ref();
this.object = $firebaseObject(rootRef);

var myLatLng = {lat: -25.363, lng: 131.044};

var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'),{
  zoom: 4,
  center: myLatLng
});

var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
  position: myLatLng,
  map: map,
  title: 'Hello World!'
});

};

}

);
```

and my JS code in another page//map.html

```js
    <script src="app.js"></script>
  <body ng-app="app">
    <div id="map" ng-app='app' ng-controller="MyLocCtrl"></div>
</body>

    <script async defer
src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=AIzaSyDUX6F83LCTZ7_uQlXzR6_Q2u6BXFIvGkY&callback=angular.element(document.getElementById('map')).firebaseObject().myfunction();">
    </script>

</html>
```

Comment: No, you cannot/should not make calls into your Angular controllers from non-Angular code. Describe what problem you're actually trying to solve. You want to include the Google API and execute a function when it's loaded?

Comment: @deceze yes exactly !! now how to do so??

Answer (score 0):

You should have the app declared as an angular module like this:

```
var app = angular.module('myApp',[]);

app.controller('MyLocCtrl', ['$scope', function($scope) {
  //
}]);
```

After that you are able to communicate with the html

Also, you already declared `ng-app='app'` in the `body`, you should remove it from the `div` element

Comment: This does not in any way illustrate how to hook into the Google API callback.

Comment: He doesn't have a working JS file that will connect to HTML. I suggested to make the app module that will have the controller. The Google API callback is another part of the problem